# Dataset to JSON conversion is better in SQL Server or C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, json

Its a 'Good Practice' Question. There are many assemblies and ways to convert the dataset from MS SQL server, convert into JSON.
So, i usually prefer the following ways.
In SQL Server,

```
SET @str = ISNULL( (SELECT *
                    FROM TEMP
                    FOR JSON path,root('Json_root'))
                 , '')
```

Or in C#

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataSet, Formatting.Indented);
```

So, I am pretty confused about which one is considered as good practice or any other better way ? also what are all the limitations in both?

Comment: As long as you can choose I would tend to use the language your team has more knowledge in

Comment: This is not a good practice question, or a good question. Better based on *what* criteria? *What* does the *expected schema* look like?

Comment: What are you going to do with that Json string? Are you sure you *won't* have to process it before sending it to your client? Will you *always* use the same database? Are *all* of your objects going to be generated by the database? If the answer is no in any of these questions, you'll have to parse the string back into objects.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I just simply asked , Json convertion in SQL Side is a good practice or not ??? Yes or No ? Why? why are you make it complicated?

Comment: Because it *is* a complicated question. In general it's a bad idea for the reasons I explained. *UNLESS* the data is already stored as JSON on the server. Data is seldom read as a DataSet or DataTable object. Json payloads rarely contain flat objects.

Comment: Another complication is the *effect* of performing such serialization on the database server. Serialization costs in memory and CPU. Tranferring string instead of binary data costs in bandwidth. What do you expect to gain by moving this load to the database instead of the web server**s**? 
It's a lot easier to load balance the *web servers*  and add caching. If you have a high traffic site, you may end up *reducing* throughput if you force the database to render Json all the time

Comment: On the other hand you could use the database as a cache for pre-generated Json payloads, trading storage to improve performance. This assumes that *reading* the payloads is more frequent than modifying them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FOR JSON is a new feature in SQL Server (with SQL Server 2016). If you want your object in plain JSON, or in a format that is achievable with SQL hacks, then you must use it. Get simple JSON in string and pass it on to client. That will be better performance getting it straight from datastore. You would not be required to bring any data from SQL for in-memory operation in C#.

But there are scenarios where JSON passed to client need not be simple, It will be many fields from many tables, and may require many queries to be executed for generation. Also, in the cases where desired formatting cannot be achieved through SQL, C# in-memory formatting remains the option.

Comment: No, the performance won't be *better* if you perform serialization on the server. You steal CPU and memory from query processing *and* end up using more network bandwidth. JSON support, just like XML, was added primarily to allow the *use*, *storage* and *querying* of JSON data without converting it.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You won't be bringing all the data from SQL server over the network, in a serialized manner, to be placed in memory. Think of the case when application is hosted in different location from database.  You will be bringing just a pre-formed string. Performance will be better.

Comment: I don't think you understand how this works, or what that string would be. It will be a *lot* bigger than the equivalent result set simply because *all* data types are larger when converted to text. Serialization will happen on the server, adding extra cost. You will **harm** performance if you generate JSON on the server for no reason

Comment: Besides, unless the schema is flat, you'll have to write a complex query to generate it.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You will have to write a query anyways, to bring it in memory as well.

Comment: Which will be a lot simpler to write, return only the actual binary values and not waste server resources serializing to Json. What is easier when you want to return objects that are nested 1-2 levels, writing a FOR JSON query  with 2-3 joins or an EF/LINQ query and serializing using Json.NET ? Which may be as simple as `myEntitySet.Where(it=>it.Id=5);`

Comment: The only case where retrieving Json from the server leads to performance gain, is when the data is actually stored as Json

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos First, if your site has millions of users, what would you prefer? I would prefer bringing a JSON string. For JSON.net one, LINQ will translate the query, prepare it, send to SQL for data fetch, bring it as in-memory dataset, then serialize it. In a multi-table complex JSON or multi-query scenario, I already have that in answer that in-memory approach will be better.

Comment: my site does have 1M users, which is why I *DON'T* want the database server to waste bandwidth and memory. I want it to run queries. And your Json.NET scenario is completely wrong. There is no dataset. There are *objects* returned by ORMs without any extra baggage. Some of them may come from other sources, or local caches. In-memory, as in in-memory tables, isn't even relevant in the discussion. *The database* already buffers data. In-memory tables are meant to speed up frequent modifications, not frequent queries

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You are spot on. We upgraded sql server from 2008 to 2019 recently and that is when I discovered the JSON PATH feature. I got really excited and so I did some testing. I have a sproc that returns data in usual rows/column format. The conversion from this to json format is done on webserver. I created an alternate version of this sproc in which the output from sql server was json directly. When I tested the two flows (1. let .net do conversion to json v/s 2. let sql server spit out json) the time taken in second scenario was almost always more. 

Great analysis btw.

Comment: I know this is an old thread but felt like giving @PanagiotisKanavos a shoutout